# intellij android hello world doesn't work "Error loading preferences"

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I try creating a standard android module in intellij idea v.9.0. I checked the "Create Hello World" option. I compiled everything. I created a AVD. I ran the sollution.
I got the error "Error loading preferences" in a window that soon dissapeared afterwords. THe emulater started ok but without my application.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA 9.x is [not compatible](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-62526) with the latest Android SDK update. Either use the workaround from a link, or update to IDEA 10 (you can use Community edition with free Android plug-in).

Comment: It still shows that error but the application does load with IDEA 10

Comment: I guess this error is harmless, this window also appears for a second, but I can't even notice the error.